# Bullboard UI working fine on local but gives page not found error on server

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, amazon-ec2

Background:
I have a node application which basically needs to run data fetching jobs using BullMQ and to have a UI I choosed Bullboard UI which was free. I am using an nginx server to reverse proxy my node app on  a specific port to my domain.

Problem:
My bullboad ui dashboard works perfectly fine on local device but once I try to access it via the example-domain/dashboard it gives 404 Not Found.

Nginx conf

```
server {
    server_name mydomain-server-name;

    root /home/ubuntu/my-project;
    index app.js;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:6969; 
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = my-domain) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name my-domain-server-name;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

App.js

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.APP_PORT;
const cors = require('cors');
const {ExpressAdapter} = require('@bull-board/express');
const {createBullBoard} = require('@bull-board/api');
const {BullMQAdapter} = require('@bull-board/api/bullMQAdapter');
const {userStatsJobQueue} = require('./bullMQ/queues/Queues');


// Express Routes
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());


const serverAdapter = new ExpressAdapter();
const bullBoard = createBullBoard({
  queues: [new BullMQAdapter(userStatsJobQueue)],
  serverAdapter: serverAdapter,
});
serverAdapter.setBasePath("/admin");

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use('/downloads/timelines', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'downloads/timelines')));
app.use(`/admin`, serverAdapter.getRouter());
```

[Bullboard ui working fine on local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8obGT.png)
[Bullboard ui not working on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7rOv.png)

I have tried allowing public folder in node js, included public folder in nginx in try_files.

Can someone please help me here :)